# Escape dollar sign ($) in Java Manifold String templates (manifold.systems)

Tags: java

I have added Manifold.systems Java library to our Maven Java project pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>systems.manifold</groupId>
        <artifactId>manifold-ext</artifactId>
        <version>${manifold-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

After this the compilation of the following line:

```
String foo = "$HIS";
```

fails compilation:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /c:/workspaces/dev/src/main/java/com/foo/bar/MyClass.java:[26,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable HIS
  location: class com.foo.bar.MyClass
[INFO] 1 error
```

Obviously, this is Manifold String templates trying to find a variable named $HIS, which is not defined in scope. So, I need to escape the $ sign, because I need it to be part of the String literal. How can I do it? If I use \$ then IntelliJ screams "Illegal escape character in string literal".

Comment: You should probably use `\\$`. Having a single backslash is an escape in string literals in Java source files themselves, so you need to double it to actually get a backslash into the string value. This of course assumes that manifold actually considers a backslash as an escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant way I found was to use annotation @DisableStringLiteralTemplates from the same Manifold library:

```
import manifold.rt.api.DisableStringLiteralTemplates;

public class FooExample {

    @DisableStringLiteralTemplates
    public void sampleMethod() {
        String foo = "$HIS";
        System.out.println("Foo is " + foo);
    }

}
```

Escaping the dollar with \$ also works, just the IntelliJ Manifold.systems plugin is required for the IDE to recognize all functions of the Manifold Java library.

A detailed description of Manifold String templates can be found here:
https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-strings